# What is the equivalent to `thing = this() || that` in Swift 3?

Tags: swift3

In most languages I can write something like this:

```
this = this() || that()
```

If `this()` returns something false, like integer 0, `that()` will be evaluated. Pretty common idiom.

Swift 3 doesn't automatically cast `Int` to `Bool` so that idiom doesn't work. What is a succinct way to do it in Swift 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no exact equivalent in Swift, as:

- No other types than `Bool` cannot be converted to `Bool`
- You cannot write a function returning `Bool` or `Int`

(*In most languages* is a little bit exaggerated, you cannot write such thing in Java, C# or many other strongly-typed languages.)

The most similar thing in Swift is [nil-coalescing operator](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH6-ID72) -- `??`.

Assume `this()` returns `Int?` (aka `Optional<Int>`), and `that()` returns `Int` (non-Optional):

```
func this() -> Int? {
    //...
    if someCondition() {
        return intValue
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}

func that() -> Int {
    //...
    return anotherIntValue
}
```

And use nil-coalescing operator like this:

```
let result = this() ?? that()
```

In this assignment, if `this()` returns non-nil value, then `that()` is not evaluated, and that non-nil value is assigned to `result`. When `this()` returns `nil`, `that()` is evaluated and the value is assigned to `result`.

Answer (score 1):

The `nil` coalescing operator as covered by [@OOPer:s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41052764/4573247) is the fit for purpose idiom here, but as a side-note, you *could* implement functionality as the one your describe by overloading the `||` operator, e.g. for types that conform to some type constraint. E.g. using `Integer` as type constraint:

```
extension Bool {
    init<T : Integer>(_ value: T) {
        self.init(value != 0)
    }
}

func ||<T: Integer>(lhs: T, rhs: @autoclosure () -> T) -> T {
    return Bool(lhs) ? lhs : rhs()
}

var thisNum = 0
let thatNum = 12
thisNum = thisNum || thatNum
print(thisNum) // 12
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but that's way more global effect than I want.